# How to plot different month comparison in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show growth of new job seekers through coronatime months.
So I filtered a table of the stats i need from the complete df and i called it 'dist.newseek'

```
 Cdata <- structure(list(Month = c(
  "2020-01", "2020-01", "2020-01", "2020-01",
  "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-02", "2020-02", "2020-02", "2020-02",
  "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-03", "2020-04",
  "2020-04", "2020-04", "2020-04", "2020-04"
), District = c(
  "Dan",
  "Jerusalem", "North", "Sharon", "South", "Dan", "Jerusalem",
  "North", "Sharon", "South", "Dan", "Jerusalem", "North", "Sharon",
  "South", "Dan", "Jerusalem", "North", "Sharon", "South"
), NewSeekers = c(
  6551L,
  3589L, 6154L, 4131L, 4469L, 5529L, 2721L, 5061L, 3464L, 3612L,
  231315L, 137479L, 159445L, 123753L, 104868L, 55038L, 33995L,
  40572L, 31373L, 23914L
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I'm trying to find the best way to show the growth of NewSeekers between January to April
If you have any other plot suggestion i'll take it

As for the problem, I used ggplot with `geom_text` but the circle is not full and the text isn't clear at all

Here's the code I used:

```
dist.newseek <- Cdata %>% 
  group_by(Month,District) %>% 
  summarise(NewSeekers=sum(NewSeekers))


ggplot(dist.newseek, aes(x="", y=NewSeekers, group=District, color=District, fill=District)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(NewSeekers,
                               " (",
                               scales::percent(NewSeekers / sum(NewSeekers)),
                               ")")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + facet_wrap(~ Month) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

And the plot:

[image: Pie chart example]

Comment: You want the percentages to be calculated within each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The issue is that you map the number of job seekers on `y` instead of the percentages. Simply compute the percentages and map these on `y`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dist.newseek <- Cdata %>% 
  group_by(Month,District) %>% 
  summarise(NewSeekers = sum(NewSeekers)) %>% 
  # Compute percentages
  mutate(NewSeekersPct = NewSeekers / sum(NewSeekers))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'Month' (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(dist.newseek, aes(x="", y=NewSeekersPct, group=District, color=District, fill=District)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(NewSeekers,
                               "\n(",
                               # Use the computed pct
                               scales::percent(NewSeekersPct, accuracy = .1),
                               ")")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Month) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention! it worked exactly as i expected and I didn't even notice the precent issue. Marked your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the percentages to be calculated within each month.
Then you probably want to group by the month and summarise.

```
group_by(dist.newseek, Month) %>%
  mutate(percent=NewSeekers / sum(NewSeekers)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=percent, fill=District)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Month, ncol=3) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(NewSeekers,
                             "\n (",
                             scales::percent(percent, accuracy=1),
                             ")")),
          position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=1.5) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=10),
        legend.position = c(0.7, 0.3)) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]